# C Syntax error after using #define

Tags: c

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 to write a C code. This is the piece of code that I defined :

```
#define setImagVal_Matrix(matrix,type,x,y,val) \
(getImagVal_Matrix(matrix,type,x,y) = (val))
```

Then I am using it inside this function :

```
for(bands=0; bands < no_of_bands; bands++) {
outputmatrix[bands] =  new_Matrix(yrange,xrange,getDataType_Image(inputImage),getDataFormat_Image(inputImage));
    for(r=0; r < no_of_rows; r++) {
        for(c=0; c < no_of_cols; c++) {
            if(c<x1 || c>x2 || r<y1 || r>y2)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                  setImagVal_Matrix(outputmatrix[bands],getDataType_Matrix(outputmatrix[bands]),c-x1,r-y1,123);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, it shows me this error on setImagVal_Matrix function call:
     **"Error:expected an expression"**

And when I build the solution , here is the output which shows a syntax error on the same line:
    **1>c:\cviplab-net-2010\cviplab\crop.c(50): error C2059: syntax error : ')'**

After spending couple of hours, I still cannot find the cause of the error . Any idea how to fix it?

EDIT:
I analyzed the pre-processed file and found the syntax error but still I don't know how to fix it. Here is the line which makes the error :
  `((((((outputmatrix[bands])->data_type) **)((outputmatrix[bands])->iptr))[r-y1][c-x1]) =     (123));`
the error is for the `)`  after `**`

Comment: How is `getImagVal_Matrix` defined?

Comment: Did you try without the macro? it will help u to identify the problem if there is any

Comment: `#define getImagVal_Matrix(matrix,type,x,y) \
   (((type **)((matrix)->iptr))[y][x])`  @Blagovest Buyukliev

Answer (score 2):

Just stop using macros as functions.  Try this:

```
inline void setImagVal_Matrix(int matrix, int type, int x, int y, int val) {
    getImagVal_Matrix(matrix, type, x, y) = val;
}
```

Change the `int` types as appropriate, and you'll get the compiler helping you with useful error messages instead of cryptic ones.  Heck, it'll even help you figure out the argument types.

Comment: `getImagVal_Matrix()` is another micro itself and it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Within your macro, you do an assignment to something that does not look like an lvalue. Do you mean `==`?

Comment: Do you see something that I don't? I can't see what `getImagVal_Matrix()` returns. (Hence making your answer just by your assumption).

Comment: Your right, it is an assumption, that's why I wrote "not look like". However, since C function (othern than C++) can not return references, there are only few possiblities (e.g., it is another macro) that produce a valid lvalue.

Comment: Actually all these micros are defined in a library than I am using . I didn't define the micro myself. The library is CVIP which is for image processing.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose at least to use brackets for the macro arguments:

```
#define setImagVal_Matrix((matrix),(type),(x),(y),(val)) \
       (getImagVal_Matrix((matrix),(type),(x),(y)) = (val))
```

Also, to see if it is really bracket issue, you can try to look at preprocessed file.

But, actually using macro for this purpose is not a good one practice. If you care about function call you can make the function `inline`:

```
inline void setImagVal_Matrix(matrix,type,x,y,val) {
    getImagVal_Matrix(matrix,type,x,y) = val;
}
```

In spite of the fact that `inline` is **only recommendation for the compiler**, this will allow to avoid a lot of compilation errors and hardly debugging run-time errors.

Comment: I checked the preprocessed file and I edited the question.Now I know where the error happends but still cannot fix it. Thanks

Comment: @EhsanEsl I also would like to recommend you using a function instead of macro.

Comment: I don'e have any other choice  since it is a library that I am using . I edited the question and you can see where the problem occurs. Any idea?